# Static global C-like variables in Ruby

Tags: ruby, global-variables

Does Ruby has static global variables?

With this I mean global variables only accessible from the file where they were defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: **No**.

The long answer is more complicated.

There's only one global namespace in Ruby and any alterations to it from any code will have the effect of changing it for all code. To keep things local you need to scope them to a particular context, typically `module` or `class`. For example:

```
module PrivateStuff
  @private_variable = "Private (mostly)"

  def self.expose_private_variable
    @private_variable
  end
end
```

Note this doesn't prevent others from accessing your private variables using `instance_variable_get` or techniques like that.

This usually isn't a big deal since global variables are usually a sign of bad design and should be avoided unless there's no alternative, a case that's exceedingly rare.

Unlike compiled languages which enforce very strict rules when it comes to data access, Ruby leaves it up to the programmer to be disciplined and simply *not* do it in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for both short and long explanation. I use Ruby more like a scripting language rather than an Object Oriented one. And in my microservices architecture I've found that a few global variables simplify things a lot (mostly when I am prototyping), however sometimes those global variables have the same name and things goes weirdly wrong. For that reason I was looking something as the static global variables in C.

Comment: Your observation that "sometimes those global variables have the same name" is *exactly* why using global variables is a bad plan from the outset. Ruby makes it extremely easy to organize things into modules so there's really no excuse to not do it. Even in quick utility scripts, creating a container class to encapsulate your logic is super simple and makes the code considerably more readable.

Comment: Interesting, I will do some research about that. Thanks again.